# Getting an error when importing Excel file to SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, powershell, import

I want to import an Excel file into my SQL server DB. Here is my code below:

```cs
$dir = "\\server\files\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir |
          Where-Object {$_.name -like "*Data Action source *"} |
          Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 1
Write-Output "The latest file is: $latest"
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "instance1" -DatabaseName "db1" -SchemaName dbo -TableName Table1 -InputData $latest -Force
Write-Output "The latest file is $latest. Let's start the import"
```

The code picks the latest file nicely but when it comes to inserting into a database its failing with the error below:

> Write-SqlTableData : A mapping between .Net type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' and SQL type for column 'Directory' was not found. Consider removing the column with that type and repeat the operation

Comment: `-InputData $latest` -> `-InputData $latest.FullName`?

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I tried your method, yes it works but the table now has weird contents now i.e columns that I dont know where they are coming fromsee below:



Length Chars

Answer (score 0):

From the error: The variable `$latest` is of the type `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`, which is not expected by the `Write-SqlTableData` command's `-InputData` parameter.

Run this line in the console for the documentation:

```
Get-Help Write-SqlTableData -Full
```

There, you will see this entry for `-InputData`

```
-InputData <PSObject>
    Specifies the data to write to the database.

    Typical input data is a System.Data.DataTable, but you can specify System.Data.DataSet or
    System.Data.DateRow objects.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    named
    Default value                none
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

So the solution is to convert the csv into a format that this command can understand. The first step is to actually import the data into PowerShell as the moment all you have is file information (path, size etc)

Below, I have cast the CSV as `psobject` data type. This may still give you an error. For converting to `System.Data.Datable` which will be accepted, [check out this link](https://www.spjeff.com/2015/04/21/datatable-in-powershell-for-crazy-fast-filters/)

```
dir = "\\server\files\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir |
          Where-Object {$_.name -like "*Data Action source *"} |
          Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 1
Write-Output "The latest file is: $latest"

# Import CSV to get the data
$csvData = Import-csv $latest.FullName

# Convert to psobject. This may still be rejected; I can't test. If it is, convert to DataTable.
$thingToImport = [psobject]$csvData

Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "instance1" -DatabaseName "db1" -SchemaName dbo -TableName Table1 -InputData $thingToImport -Force
Write-Output "The latest file is $latest. Let's start the import"
```

Comment: Hi gms, the file am importing is an excel file not csv. Not sure if I should follow the same process here as you said above. Please clarify?

Comment: The above will not work with `xls`/`xlsx` files; the `Import-Csv` function will fail. You can do this programmatically with Excel but there will be several steps. Is saving the file as a `csv` beforehand an option?

Comment: saving as a cv might not be an option because the import process will be automated in the future. I have tried to use your method above using an excel file but went into errors that I dont know how to fix: i.e. Write-SqlTableData : The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination